# apache .htaccess to nginx rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

.htaccess file with following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^tag/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ hashtag.php?hashtag=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

and in nginx rewrite, i set like this

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /profile.php?username=$1;
            }
    if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^tag/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /hashtag.php?hashtag=$1;
    }

}
```

i can visit domain.com/hashtag.php?hashtag=123, domain.com/profile.php?username=name, and also i can visit domain.com/name, but i can't visit domain.com/tag/123, it shows 404 error. Can you help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe you can change the order of rewrites, put tag first :)?

Comment: @DusanBajic also the same result, 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a error in my nginx rewrite configure, it should be

```
rewrite ^/tag/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /hashtag.php?hashtag=$1;
```

I miss the /, close this question.